# How to avoid icon-within-icon when using "Add to Home screen"

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, app-icons

With some apps like Chrome and the Google app it's possible to add shortcuts to content by using "Add to home screen". Unfortunately the icons created for these shortcuts have a small app icon placed over the lower right corner of the image representing the content. This makes things unnecessarily complicated and ugly on the home screen. I'm trying to find a way to easily avoid these icons-within-icons.

For example if you search for "weather" in the Google app, then select the first result, then select "Add to home screen" in that content's three-bars menu, you get a shortcut to the current weather on your home screen. Similarly, if you go to news.bbc.co.uk in Chrome and select "Add to Home screen" in that tab's three-dots menu you get a shortcut to BBC News on your home screen.

The resulting icons will look like this:

[image]

The microphone-over-cloud-over-sun is a particularly egregious mixed metaphor and visual mess, but even for content that has a simpler image like BBC News the icon-within-icon is ugly and unnecessary. After all, I created these shortcuts myself so I know which apps they will open, and if I ever forget I only have to tap on the shortcut to be reminded... I certainly don't need to be reminded by visual clutter every time I view my home screen.

The icons-within-icons get created whether I use the Google Now Launcher which is the default on my Nexus phone or or whether I use an alternative home app like the Nova Launcher. With the Nova Launcher I could manually change the icons to what I want after I create the shortcuts, but to do that I'd need an unadulterated version of the icon representing the shortcut's content, and those are not always readily available. For example I haven't yet found the Google app's weather icon without the microphone, and even the BBC News logo seems to only be available as a rectangle that would need to be resized and cropped to be used as an icon. I'm trying to avoid having to do such manual edits to get the shortcut icons I need: After all, the system itself has access to the desired icons since it's able to disfigure them by overlaying its app-icon-in-the-corner :-).

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: On my Galaxy s5 using touch wiz launcher, i don't have those icons. It's possible that this is device specific or launcher specific

Comment: For a person who had created many app shortcuts can easily recognize whether that icon related to which app and can manage it. Otherwise, you cannot understand whether it is app or shortcut.

Comment: Could you add information about your device and launcher app? Default or custom?

Comment: @arieljannai: Device = Nexus 5X, launcher = default Google Now launcher, with the same results with the custom Nova Launcher.

Comment: @Rahul: Yes, I think I understand the reasoning behind the decision made by someone to have icons-within-icons. As suggested in my question, this reasoning is in my opinion quite flawed as it leads to ugly home screens for typical users with little benefits for the users you describe.